# Can a combination of Grilling and Baking be used for Chicken?

Tags: chicken, chicken-breast, chicken-wings

I was wondering If 1st Grilling the chicken to chrisp up the outer surface and then baking it to get is cooked all over and retain the Moistness will work .

Can this give me a Moist and Chrispy chicken ? For how much time should each method be applied ?

Comment: What do you mean by "grilling"? Are you in the US or U.K.?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about cooking technique...yes, you can sear chicken on the grill and then finish cooking by baking in the oven.  You can also do the reverse (oven then grill). There are plenty of recipes floating around the internet (recipe requests are off topic for this site).